# How to compute the following integral with the gauss formula?

Tags: integration, analysis, transformation, gaussian-integral

I have the following question.

> I need to compute the following integral $$\int_A xy+yz+zx \,\,\,dxdydz$$ for $A=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: x,y,z\geq 0, x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1\}$ with the gauss formula.

My Idea was the following:

We have the following situation:
[image]

I remark that $\partial A=B_{xy}\cup B_{yz}\cup B_{xz} \cup S$. Now I see that if I take $$F(x,y,z)=(xyz,xyz,xyz)$$ then $div(F)=xy+yz+zx$. In addition I remark that $F$ is zero on $B_{xy}, B_{yz}, B_{xz}$ so it is enough to compute $$\int_S \langle F(x,y,z),\nu(x,y,z)\rangle \,\,\,dS(x,y,z)$$. Since this is a sphere it is clear that the outer normal vector $\nu(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$ thus we have $$\langle F(x,y,z),\nu(x,y,z)\rangle=x^2yz+xy^2z+xyz^2$$ so I have $$\int_S x^2yz+xy^2z+xyz^2\,\,\,dS(x,y,z)$$Since this situation is symmetric it is enough to compute only one integral. Therefore I wanted to compute $$\int_S x^2yz\,\,\, dS(x,y,z)$$.

But here I have some problems, I don't see how to procede. I thought that maybe we could use the transformation theorem but I'm not sure. Could someone maybe help me how to proceed from here?

So I mean with the transformation theorem I would get $$\int_S x^2yz \,\,\,dS(x,y,z)=\int_0^{\frac{pi}{2}} \int_0^{\frac{pi}{2}} \sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\rho) \sin(\theta)\sin(\rho)\cos(\theta) \,|sin(\theta)| \,\,\,\,dS(\theta,\rho)$$

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on further clarifications from you, you are supposed to use gram matrix.

The surface is, $r(\theta, \phi) = (\cos\theta \sin\phi, \sin\theta \sin\phi, \cos\phi), 0 \leq \theta, \phi \leq \pi/2$

Unit normal vector, $\hat n = (\cos\theta \sin\phi, \sin\theta \sin\phi, \cos\phi)$

$dS = \sqrt{\text {det} ~G} ~ d\phi ~d\theta$

To write gram matrix,

$v = (\cos\theta \cos\phi, \sin\theta \cos\phi, - \sin\phi)$
$w = (- \sin\theta \sin\phi, \cos\theta \sin\phi, 0)$

$\displaystyle G=\left(\begin{array}{rrr} \langle v,v \rangle & \langle v,w \rangle \\ \langle w,v \rangle & \langle w,w \rangle \end{array}\right) =\left(\begin{array}{rrr} 1  & 0 \\ 0 & \sin^2\phi \end{array}\right)$

$\text {det } G = \sin^2\phi$

So the integral becomes,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} (\vec F \cdot \hat n) ~ \sin\phi ~ d\phi ~ d\theta$

Comment: sorry but I don't see where I parametrize my surface as you said?

Comment: Sorry there are still some questions. So as I understood your answer, the computations I have done so far are correct right? But I still do not see how I simplify $S(\theta,\rho)$. So I mean I used the spherical coordinates for the transformation theorem and get $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^4(\theta) \cos^2(\rho)\sin(\rho)\cos(\theta) \,\,dS(\theta, \rho)$$right? but then I need to use the same parametrisation for the surface $S$ or not?

Comment: so but we have learnt that $dS$ is equal to the root of the determinant of the gram matrix of the parametrisation of $S$? Sorry I don't see through your answer

Comment: OK so you are using gram matrix, you should have mentioned. It comes to the same but a bit lengthier. What I have shown is simply using the normal vector and then Jacobian or using $r_{\phi} \times r_{\theta}$. I will try and point to an answer using gram matrix that I wrote sometime back. Let me find it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know that there was a different way of doing this, my fault I'm really sorry. Yes we always used the gram matrix

Comment: Sorry I somehow didn't see that you changed your answer. Hmm okei makes sence how you get to your $dS$ but don't we also need the transformation theorem i.e. the absolut value of the determinant of the change of variable matrix

Comment: Because I somehow have some problems understanding this since we have changed coordinates in my opinion we should also use the transformation theorem. Or has this nothing to do with the change of coordinates since we only use our parametrisation of the surface and the definition of an integral over a submanifold, and unfortunately it looks really similar to a change of coordinates?

Comment: No when you parametrize a surface in $3$D in terms of two variables $u$ and $v$, gram matrix or $|r_u \times r_v|$ does map surface area element to area in uv i.e. $dS = \sqrt{\text{det }G} ~ du ~ dv$. There is no Jacobian required unless you then change $du ~ dv$ to another set of two variables. For example, if you parametrize the surface using $x$ and $y$ and get $dS = \sqrt{\text{det }G} ~ dx ~ dy$. Subsequently you change $dx ~ dy$ to polar coordinates $dr ~ d\theta$ then yes you need Jacobian. But if you parametrized the surface directly in $(r, \theta)$, then you don't.

Comment: aha so I think I was confused since it looked to me as I did a change of variable, but this is only the definition of $dS$. But when I parametrize my surface with the map $\phi$ using $x,y$ for example and then $dS$ is too difficult to compute I can first change coordinates (e.g. into polar coordinates $\psi$) using the jacobian. Then i get $dS(\theta, \rho)$ instead of $dS(x,y)$ and then apply the definition of $dS$ i.e. $dS=\sqrt{\det G}\,\,d\theta \,\,d\rho$. right, where now $G$ is the jacobian of $\phi\circ \psi$. Or am I still wrong?

Comment: You are getting there now but a little correction - when you parametrize the surface with map $\phi$ using $x, y$, you have $dS = \sqrt{\text{det }G} ~ dx ~ dy$ and you have the integral. Now if you want to do change of variable from $(x, y)$ to $(r, \theta)$, you can do so by finding Jacobian of transformation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133497/discussion-between-aprozz-and-math-lover).